# Remove row from data frame A, when column value from data frame B is not similar

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

***My Target***

I'm trying to create a new data frame of which is formed by comparing columns from different data frames.

More specifically, when a column value from `ColumnA` isn't alike/present in `ColumnB`, *that* whole row is disregarded and not included in `new_df`

***Data Frames***

```
>>> df

                ColumnA             Stats
0               Cake                872
1               Cheese Cake         912  
2               Egg                 62
3               Raspb Jam           091
4               Bacon               123
5               Bread               425

>>> df1

                ColumnB  
0               Cake  
1               Cheese Cake    
3               Raspberry Jam  
4               Bacon
```

***My Attempt***

Since I'm not sure on how to achieve this, I have done my best to produce the following, although I know it probably won't achieve my expected output:

```
new_df = df[df['ColumnA'].str.strip() in df1['ColumnB'].str.split()]
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

***Expected Output***

As you can see, for the column values that aren't present in `df1`, the rows are erased from `df`. In this case, `Bread` and `Egg` are both not present, consequently, new_df doesn't contain their `rows`

```
>>> new_df
                ColumnA         Stats
0               Cake            872
1               Cheese Cake     912  
3               Raspberry Jam   091
4               Bacon           123
```

---

**EDIT:**

`Raspb Jam` ***is also kept in the new DF because it is SIMILAR to Raspberry Jam*** at a very basic level.

Comment: As @Psidom points out, you need to [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`. The default mode is `how='inner'`, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Psidom This gets rid of more rows than expected

Comment: @3novak His suggestion doesn't seem to work. I have edited the DF, missed out a detail. I'm looking for similar matches as stated in the title :)

Comment: @Psidom I have edited the DF, missed out a detail.

Comment: Yes it wouldn't work if you attempt to integrate some natural language processing here. It only supports exact match.

Comment: @Psidom It's far from 'nlp'. That's why in my attempt I tried using .strip() and .split()

Comment: You can't go from `Raspb` to `Raspberry` by `strip` and `split`, it is a stem process which is a pretty standard process in nlp? You may still be able to work around with some regex but I doubt how far you can go.

Comment: @Psidom Alright :) In an if statement, something such as the following would work: `if 'Raspb Jam'.lower().strip() in "raspberry jam".split(): ...` . So if all I'm looking for is a very 'basic' similarity, I can't understand why such a thing isn't possible.

Comment: If I understand correctly and you just need the strings to be the same try: `df.ColumnA = df. ColumnA.map(lambda x: x.replace('Raspb Jam', 'Raspberry Jam'))`.  Then try the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map function to provide explicit lookup.

```
df = DataFrame( {'ColumnA' : ['Cake' ,'Cheese Cake','Egg' , 'Raspb Jam' ,'Bacon' ,'Bread'],'Value' : [872,912,62,91,123, 425]})
df1 = DataFrame(['Cake' ,'Cheese Cake','Raspberry Jam','Bacon'],columns=['ColumnB'])
value_map = {'Raspberry Jam' : 'Raspb Jam' }
df1.ColumnB = df1.ColumnB.map(lambda x : value_map.get(x,x))
df1.rename(columns={'ColumnB' : 'ColumnA'},inplace=True)
df.merge(df1)
   ColumnA  Value
0         Cake    872
1  Cheese Cake    912
2    Raspb Jam     91
3        Bacon    123
```

Alternatively , use left_on and right_on param to specify the column name(s) to merge.

```
df.merge(df1,how='inner',left_on='ColumnA',right_on='ColumnB')[['ColumnA','Value']]
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks - May you please briefly explain the following: `.map(lambda x : value_map.get` . Thanks very much! :)

Comment: Series has a 'map' method for applying an element-wise function.Please refer below link for more information.http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html.

Comment: I created a  value_map dictionary to specify an explicit mapping. value_map.get(x, x) is a lookup and it returns original value if no mapping provided in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have the energy to take care of all the edge cases.  But you may find this method helpful.  If not, no worries.

- use `set` and `<=` to test is the characters in `df` are in `df1` as a measure of similarity.
- leverage `numpy`'s broadcasting to help out

---

```
a = df.ColumnA.apply(set).values
b = df1.ColumnB.apply(set).values

print(df[(a[:, None] <= b).any(1)])

       ColumnA  Stats
0         Cake    872
1  Cheese Cake    912
3    Raspb Jam     91
4        Bacon    123
```

---

***Response to comments***

You can force the columns to be `str` with

```
a = df.ColumnA.astype(str).apply(set).values
b = df1.ColumnB.astype(str)..apply(set).values
```

***Explanation***

- `a[:, None]` reshapes the single dimensional `a` array to a 2-D array.  This enables me to perform numpy broadacasting
- `set` objects use `<=` to perform `issubset` checks.  Since `a` and `b` are all `set`s, we do `a[:, None] <= b]` to perform every pairwise comparison of is `a[i]` a subset of `b[j]` for all i, j.
- `(a[:, None] <= b).any(1)` checks to see if `a[i]` was a subset of `b[j]` for any j.  Meaning did I find at least one element in `b` that `a[i]` was a subset of.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try it out, although, as the numbers may fluctuate, they sometimes appear as floats. Therefore, I believe it is causing the following issue: `TypeError: 'float' object is not itterable`. It there a way to solve this?

Comment: Sorry the the consecutive question - I would greatly appreciate it if you could explain the following: `a[:, None] <= b).any(1)]` briefly :) Thanks, sorry for the struggle caused.